# $x_1+x_2+x_3=20,$ $x_1 \le 4$ and $ x_2, x_3 \le 9$

Tags: combinatorics

$x_1+x_2+x_3=20,$ $x_1 \le 4$ and $  x_2, x_3 \le 9$.

I know how to solve the problem when $x_i\ge s,\,s\in\Bbb Z$ , by using a slack variable. But I'm not sure when it's $\le$ since it's telling me that it has a limit that it must not exceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y_1 = 4 - x_1$, $y_2 = 9 - x_2$ and $y_3 = 9 - x_3$. Then the inequalities become $y_1, y_2, y_3 ≥ 0$.

In terms of the new variables, we have:
$$(4 - y_1) + (9 - y_2) + (9 - y_3) = 20$$
$$ \Rightarrow 22-(y_1+y_2+y_3)=20$$
$$ \Rightarrow y_1+y_2+y_3=2$$

and this can be solved using stars and bars to get $6$ non-negative integer solutions.

You can generalise this method where there are more possible values of $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

Comment: Definitely an elegant way. (+1) :-)

Comment: What is "stars and bars"? Sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: It's a technique to count the number of ways indistinguishable objects can be grouped. The Brilliant article for this is [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) (there's another article also on Wikipedia).